# Android M - Upgrade my app with a new permission

Tags: android

In addition to discussion here: [Android M permission install/update behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392700/android-m-permission-install-update-behavior) , I would like to know what happens in the following case:

I have added a new non-critical permission (Other app permissions - like set an alarm, view wi-fi connections etc.) to my app, and I want to publish this new version of my app as an upgrade to my existing app. The new version has target SDK max set to 23.

1. App with target SDK max 22 installed on Android M device - When this new version of my app upgrades on the M device, will the user need to explicitly grant access to the new permission?
2. App with target SDK max 22 installed on Android L device - When this new version of my app upgrades on the L device, will the user need to explicitly grant access to the new permission, or will auto-upgrade word without user interaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you target lower than API 23 then the old permission model applies. The user needs to grant at install, but on a M device he can revoke the permission in the settings. After your app update the permission state does not change for this permission.
2. Only M devices support the new permission model, hence the user needs to grant at install time. On a M device the user would grant request at runtime.

Comment: For #1 - What I meant to ask is this: I am adding a new non-dangerous permission in by app update. Will the user need to explicitly grant this permission? Will this permission be auto granted?

Comment: A normal permission is granted by default. No user interaction is needed. And this permission cannot be revoked on M devices.

Comment: That is what I wanted to hear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any app with lower version than 23 will by default get all the dangerous permissions enabled. So you don't have to request any permission if your sdk version specified in manifest is less than 23.